# Need to join lines in data file. Data lines are inconsistent

Tags: awk, sed

I need to join lines in an input data file using keys.  Specifically data line 1 will always start with a 'C1',  data line 2 will always start with a 'J1'.
**There will not be a 'C1' in every case.**  Some of the 'J1' lines exist without the preceding 'C1' lines.   Best case is I can retrieve the 'C1 || J1' lines into an output file and the 'J1' singularities into a separate output file.   I have searched this site for the answer for most of the day and it is not apparent to me.

Using an odd / even approach is out due to the single 'J1' lines.
I know nothing about Perl and we don't use it at work,  so Perl is out.
I am sort of restricted to awk, sed.

OMG Forgot the Sample input and Sample outputs.  My bad.

Sample Input:
C111416655020090209IP

J1114166550SA0165235Z00000X295053911A

C112411158820060930OP

J1124111588DE2095332B00000X29650

J11241115887145143336C0003X296501145D

J11241115887814653336C0003X296501145D

C104327839320060503OP

J1043278393548223332B00000X295053424A

Sample Output file 1:
C111416655020090209IP J1114166550SA0165235Z00000X295053911A

C112411158820060930OP J1124111588DE2095332B00000X29650

C104327839320060503OP J1043278393548223332B00000X295053424A

Sample Output file 2:
J11241115887145143336C0003X296501145D

J11241115887814653336C0003X296501145D

State machine not likely here at work.

Thanks in advance.
Robert Hohlt, Jr.

Comment: Show sample input and your desired output for that sample input.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a state machine http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Comment: Since you have searched this site for the answer for most of the day you will have no doubt noticed that sample input and expected output are always required to get people thinking about helping you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
awk '/^J1/{print p, $0; p=""; next} {p=$0}' file
```

but until you post some sample input and expected output, it's just a rough guess.